# Error compiling fortran file on a mac

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

Not a super mac user and have never used fortran, so please bear with me. I am trying to use gfortran to compile a file and am getting an error from the following line:

```
open(unit=4,file=*,status='old',READONLY,iostat=iopen,
 &   err=9999)
```

If I remove the READONLY part, the error persists as:

Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `1` marker just below the location in the line where the compiler sees the syntax error. If the `1` is below a comma, then the error is in the next statement (for example, if it is under the comma after `unit=4`, then the error is in `file=*`).

Here are a few things:

1. `unit=4` I never use single digit unit numbers, as these might be reserved for things like standard in/out or error out.
2. `file=*` That one is weird. I don't think you can use wildcards in standard Fortran, try to point it to a specific file here.
3. `READONLY` This makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. I assume what you need is `action='read'`, but once you start passing arguments with `something=someval`, you can't go back to just pass some values and hope that the compiler figures out which dummy variable that's actually meant to represent.
4. `err=9999` This is an implied `GOTO`: On error, go to this label. It is strongly discouraged to use it. Since you're using `iostat` anyway, I'd suggest rather check for that return value.

Depending on what the input files are, or how the program should actually behave in case of an error opening the file, it is up to you to figure out how to get this code Fortran-compliant.